# Got a crash while calling MonoTouch.UIKit.UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion

Tags: c#, crash, xamarin.ios, uidevice

I got a crash while calling MonoTouch.UIKit.UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion. It happens on the Simulator. I couldn't reproduce it easily... I've put the debugger trace bellow.

The usage context:
The goal is to show the progress of the video being played. Because SetProgress(v, false) is not supported on iOS 4.X. The old API which was SetProgress(v) is not available anymore in MonoTouch 5.X, for the moment we don't display buffering progress.

Cheers, pboc

```
Stacktrace:

at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00026, 0xffffffff>
at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIDevice.get_SystemVersion () [0x0000b] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIDevice.g.cs:189
at Dartfish.ControlsX.DFScrubBar.SetDownloadProgressValue (single) [0x00000] in /Users/patrick/Work/Dartfish/Dartfish Mobile/Source/SDKs/SystemSDK/Source/ControlsX/MonoTouch/DFScrubBar.cs:118
at MonoTouchPresenter.Common.PlaybackControlBar.UpdateBufferingProgress () [0x00017] in /Users/patrick/Work/Dartfish/Dartfish Mobile/Source/Application/Dartfish.tv/iOS/MonoTouch/Common/Views/PlaybackControlBar.cs:461
at MonoTouchPresenter.Common.PlaybackControlBar.OnVideoPlayerViewModelPropertyChanged (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) [0x00065] in /Users/patrick/Work/Dartfish/Dartfish Mobile/Source/Application/Dartfish.tv/iOS/MonoTouch/Common/Views/PlaybackControlBar.cs:383
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x000a8>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x000a8>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00059, 0xffffffff>
at Dartfish.Common.BindableObject.RaisePropertyChanged (string) [0x0002b] in /Users/patrick/Work/Dartfish/Dartfish Mobile/Source/SDKs/CommonSDK/Source/Common/BindableObject.cs:40
at Dartfish.ViewModel.Player.VideoPlayerViewModel.videoPlayer_BufferingProgressChanged (object,Dartfish.Component.Media.VideoEventArgs) [0x00000] in /Users/patrick/Work/Dartfish/Dartfish Mobile/Source/ViewModel/PlayerViewModel/Implementations/VideoPlayer/VideoPlayerViewModel.cs:2386
at Dartfish.Component.MediaCommon.GenericMatchPlayer.RaiseEvent (Dartfish.Component.Media.VideoEventHandler,object,Dartfish.Component.Media.VideoEventArgs) [0x00006] in /Users/patrick/Work/Dartfish/Dartfish Mobile/Source/SDKs/MediaComponentSDK/Source/MediaComponentCommon/Implementations/VideoPlayer/VideoPlayer.cs:2434
at Dartfish.Component.MediaCommon.GenericMatchPlayer.OnBufferingProgressChanged (object,Dartfish.Component.Media.VideoEventArgs) [0x00000] in /Users/patrick/Work/Dartfish/Dartfish Mobile/Source/SDKs/MediaComponentSDK/Source/MediaComponentCommon/Implementations/VideoPlayer/VideoPlayer.cs:2406
at Dartfish.Component.MediaCommon.VideoControl.OnBufferingProgressChanged (object,Dartfish.Component.Media.VideoEventArgs) [0x00096] in /Users/patrick/Work/Dartfish/Dartfish Mobile/Source/SDKs/MediaComponentSDK/Source/MediaComponentCommon/Implementations/VideoPlayer/VideoControl.cs:2621
at Dartfish.Component.MediaCommon.VideoControl.TimerCallback2 () [0x00366] in /Users/patrick/Work/Dartfish/Dartfish Mobile/Source/SDKs/MediaComponentSDK/Source/MediaComponentCommon/Implementations/VideoPlayer/VideoControl.cs:2459
at Dartfish.Component.MediaCommon.VideoControl.m_timer_Tick (object,System.EventArgs) [0x00000] in /Users/patrick/Work/Dartfish/Dartfish Mobile/Source/SDKs/MediaComponentSDK/Source/MediaComponentCommon/Implementations/VideoPlayer/VideoControl.cs:2166
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.InternalTick () [0x00019] in /Users/patrick/Work/Dartfish/Dartfish Mobile/Source/SDKs/CommonSDK/Source/Common/DispatcherTimer.cs:203
at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSActionDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/shared/Foundation/NSAction.cs:48
at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0004e, 0xffffffff>
at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0009f, 0xffffffff>
at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x00042] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:29
at MonoTouchPresenter.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Users/patrick/Work/Dartfish/Dartfish Mobile/Source/Application/Dartfish.tv/iOS/MonoTouch/Main.cs:16
at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00050, 0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

0   MonoTouchPresenter                  0x0007e5cc mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 284
1   MonoTouchPresenter                  0x00009af8 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 248
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x94b5159b _sigtramp + 43
3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x94b17903 szone_malloc_should_clear + 899
5   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x94b1866b szone_malloc + 24
6   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x94b4e962 malloc_zone_malloc + 77
7   CoreFoundation                      0x0175ca88 __CFAllocatorSystemAllocate + 24
8   CoreFoundation                      0x0175ca63 CFAllocatorAllocate + 147
9   CoreFoundation                      0x0175c8de _CFRuntimeCreateInstance + 270
10  CoreFoundation                      0x0175ed13 __CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3 + 1955
11  CoreFoundation                      0x017664be CFStringCreateWithBytes + 94
12  CoreFoundation                      0x01783b56 _CFPropertyListCreateWithData + 822
13  CoreFoundation                      0x0178381a CFPropertyListCreateWithData + 58
14  libMobileGestalt.dylib              0x0537a069 load_dict + 433
15  libMobileGestalt.dylib              0x0537a351 copySystemVersionDictionary + 204
16  libMobileGestalt.dylib              0x0537be70 copyProductVersion + 20
17  libMobileGestalt.dylib              0x0537abd2 copyRealAnswer + 132
18  UIKit                               0x00b87a65 -[UIDevice deviceInfoForKey:] + 32
19  UIKit                               0x00b87c53 -[UIDevice systemVersion] + 44
20  ???                                 0x0bb60763 0x0 + 196478819
21  ???                                 0x111c9d04 0x0 + 287087876
22  ???                                 0x111c9bc5 0x0 + 287087557
23  ???                                 0x111c9a0c 0x0 + 287087116
24  ???                                 0x111c64c0 0x0 + 287073472
25  ???                                 0x0d09caaa 0x0 + 218745514
26  ???                                 0x0d09ca41 0x0 + 218745409
27  ???                                 0x0d09ca41 0x0 + 218745409
28  ???                                 0x0d09b9b8 0x0 + 218741176
29  ???                                 0x112aa45c 0x0 + 288007260
30  ???                                 0x11210990 0x0 + 287377808
31  ???                                 0x112aa414 0x0 + 288007188
32  ???                                 0x112ab2f3 0x0 + 288010995
33  ???                                 0x112a60ac 0x0 + 287989932
34  ???                                 0x112a536c 0x0 + 287986540
35  ???                                 0x112a34a2 0x0 + 287978658
36  ???                                 0x101885b8 0x0 + 270042552
37  ???                                 0x09ddbd48 0x0 + 165526856
38  MonoTouchPresenter                  0x0000dde2 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
39  MonoTouchPresenter                  0x00153b4e mono_runtime_invoke + 126
40  MonoTouchPresenter                  0x001fbde8 monotouch_trampoline + 3416
41  Foundation                          0x005c4eb6 __NSFireTimer + 113
42  CoreFoundation                      0x0182c936 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
43  CoreFoundation                      0x0182c3d7 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 551
44  CoreFoundation                      0x0178f790 __CFRunLoopRun + 1888
45  CoreFoundation                      0x0178ed84 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
46  CoreFoundation                      0x0178ec9b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
47  GraphicsServices                    0x0286c7d8 GSEventRunModal + 190
48  GraphicsServices                    0x0286c88a GSEventRun + 103
49  UIKit                               0x009b1626 UIApplicationMain + 1163
50  ???                                 0x0bb5b005 0x0 + 196456453
51  ???                                 0x0bb5a0e0 0x0 + 196452576
52  ???                                 0x0bb59db8 0x0 + 196451768
53  ???                                 0x0bb59f2e 0x0 + 196452142
54  MonoTouchPresenter                  0x0000dde2 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
55  MonoTouchPresenter                  0x00153b4e mono_runtime_invoke + 126
56  MonoTouchPresenter                  0x00157d44 mono_runtime_exec_main + 420
57  MonoTouchPresenter                  0x001580b5 mono_runtime_run_main + 725
58  MonoTouchPresenter                  0x00068165 mono_jit_exec + 149
59  MonoTouchPresenter                  0x0000762c main + 3052
60  MonoTouchPresenter                  0x00002825 start + 53

 =================================================================
 Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
 a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
 used by your application.
 =================================================================
```

Answer (score 2):

This is memory corruption. Something (before you called CurrentDevice.SystemVersion) has corrupted memory, and then it crashes some time later (in this case when allocating memory).

Since allocating memory is quite common, it is likely that the corruption happened not long before you called CurrentDevice.SystemVersion.

I suggest you try to make a small a sample as possible, this will also probably tell you exactly where the problem is.